# f:ajax listener not fired for h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The event doesn't get fired in my controller. This is the code.

View:

```
<ui:repeat var="operation" value="#{trade.operationsSortList}">
   <tr class="operations">
       <th class="empty_cell"></th>
       <td id="operation" class="operation_cell color">#{operation.operation}</td>
       <td class="color">#{operation.time}</td>
       <td class="color">#{operation.coment}</td>
       <td class="color">
           <h:form>
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                 <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{controller.onDelete}" />
                 <f:attribute name="trade" value="#{trade}" />
              </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
           </h:form>
       </td>
   </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Controller 
{
  private ArrayList trades;
  .....
  .....

  public void onDelete(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    Trade trade = (Trade) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("trade");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**REDIT:**

I got this working, but I still have problems because I have tables, so I need to wrap the tables in a form tag, so I enclose the whole view in a form tag. My goal is just to send to the server the clicked checkbox! The request is sent to the sever, but the listener doesn't get called. The javascript event gets called. This is the code:

VIEW:

```
   <h:form>
                <table id="trades">
                    <th class="image_cell"></th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Portfolio</th>
                        <ui:repeat var="trade" value="#{controller.errorTrades}">
                            <tr class="trade error">
                                <td class="image_cell error"><h:graphicImage styleClass="expandable" url="resources/images/plus.png"></h:graphicImage></td>
                                <td id="type" class="error">#{trade.type}</td>
                                <td class="error">#{trade.portfolio}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="operations">
                                <td id="#{trade.murexId}" class="operation_row" colspan="4">
                                        <table id="operations">
                                            <tr class="header">
                                                <th class="empty_cell"></th>
                                                <th class="operation_cell">Operation</th>
                                                <th>Time Transaction</th>
                                                <th>Comment</th>
                                                <th id="delete">Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <ui:repeat var="operation" value="#{trade.operationsSortList}">
                                                <tr class="operation">
                                                    <th class="empty_cell"></th>
                                                    <td id="operation" class="operation_cell color">#{operation.operation}</td>
                                                    <td class="color">#{operation.time}</td>
                                                    <td class="color">#{operation.coment}</td>
                                                    <td class="color checkbox">
                                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="delete">
                                                            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="click" listener="#{controller.onDelete}" onevent="onDeleteProcess" />
                                                            <f:attribute name="murexId" value="#{trade.murexId}" />
                                                            <f:attribute name="operationId" value="#{operation.id}" />
                                                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                                              
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ui:repeat>
                </table>
            </h:form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@ViewScoped
public class Controller 
{
    private ArrayList trades;
    private ArrayList errorTrades = new ArrayList();

    .......code

    public boolean onDelete(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) 
    {
        long murexId = 0;
        BigDecimal operationId = null;
        boolean result = false;
        Trade trade;
        Iterator itop;
        Operation operation;
        ......code

        return true;
    }
}
```

It's pretty important for me to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What JSF impl/version? I can't reproduce your problem on Mojarra 2.1.7. I however recall ui:repeat+f:ajax inconsitenties on early versions.

Comment: Since you accepted the answer of Matt, may I assume that your problem is solved? But you mentioned that you don't want to use a command link. What exactly was the real problem and how exactly have you solved it? Or if it isn't solved, then please edit your question to include a fullworthy SSCCE. This is the **smallest possible but complete** code snippet which we can just copy'n'paste'n'run to see the problem. Get rid of as many as possible irrelevant tags/attributes like `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc as long as *you* can still reproduce the problem. Then copypaste the entire view and bean here.

Comment: Yes, I solved it. I put just one <h:form> tag out of the <ui:repeat> tags and it worked as I expected. The listener got fired in the server side and I have access to the parameters related <f:ajax> tag. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments on the way to a solution:

You have html table rows inside a `ui:repeat`. You should use a `h:dataTable` for this purpose.

The `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` has no `value` attribute. If you want to call an action method you should better use a `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton`. Then you wouldn't need the `f:attribute` and could do something like this:

```
<h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{controller.delete(trade)}"/>
```

And in your backing bean:

```
public void delete(Trade trade) {
 // delete action
}
```

Furthermore you have one form for each row. Maybe there is another wrapping form around the table. This wouldn't be valid and would be the possible cause of unexpected behavior. If you are using ajax you simply could use only one form around the table and render/execute the parts you like.

Comment: I'm using ui:repeat because one table is contained in another one + a have a lot of css. When I tried datatable I had a lot of problems. I don't want to use a commandLink tag. I used to work with python frameworks and could do this kind of calls using jquery and restful. There is no another wrapping form. Is there any way to do it like this? or I need to wrap all the tags in one form? For sure, I don't want to use a commandLike button