# f:ajax listener not invoked

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, listener

Whatever I do, I can't make sense of the listener attribute of the f:ajax tag. The method won't get invoked. I don't get any error messages. Here's an example:

### test.xhtml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>
            Example
        </title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{testBean.value}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />                    
                <f:ajax render="messages" listener="#{testBean.processAjaxBehaviour}" onevent="test" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:messages id="messages" />
        </h:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(event)
            {
                alert(event.status);
            }
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

### TestBean.java

```java
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    int value = 2;

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        value = value;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Done constructing testBean.");
    }

    public void processAjaxBehaviour(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException
    {
        System.out.println("Processing AJAX behaviour.");
    }
}
```

The function `test` is called three times, as expected, and I get the status "success". The listener `processAjaxBehaviour` isn't called however.

The `init` method is called. The second `option` element rendered by the `f:selectItem` gets selected as expected.

Comment: Your onevent is wrong, you can use event="click" or event="change" for example.

Comment: do you see any errors in the browser console ? does the alert being fired? change ` if(event.status == 'success')
                    alert('success');` into  `alert(event.status);` to see if its being stopped after the `complete`

Comment: whats exactly not working ? `processAjaxBehaviour` not being called or js function?

Comment: As he describe, the listener is not called. Is there a equivalent of a4j:log in pure JSF 2 that he could use to debug client side?

Comment: @Daniel I updated the question. The function `test` is now called three times, as expected, and I get the status "success". The listener `processAjaxBehaviour` isn't called however.

Comment: @Spomf any chance you declared your bean in faces-config too?

Comment: @Daniel No, I rely on the annotation only.

Comment: try to change `public void processAjaxBehaviour(AjaxBehaviourEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException ` into `public void processAjaxBehaviour(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {` (remove throws)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Log what client side? In case you havn't noticed; I update the messages component (but it doesn't get any messages).

Comment: add `@PostConstruct
 public void init() { //some printlines here` to see if the bean is being created at all

Comment: @Daniel It is the complete signature for an AJAX listener method. It should work without the throws part, as you suggest, and I've already tested it without luck. The bean is created.

Comment: Add a value with a getter/setter, first time I see a form without values... see that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670700/fajax-listener-not-fired-for-hselectbooleancheckbox

Comment: no idea... only a guess , try adding `implements Serializable` to the bean...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Updated the question with a value added to the `h:selectOneMeny`. No luck. @Daniel No luck implementing `Serializable` either.

Comment: Have you special settings inside web.xml like javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING set to false etc ?

Comment: I have `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` set to `false`. I set it to true, but it didn't help. I also have custom values on `javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES` and `javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR`, but I don't see how any of these relate to the problem.

Comment: How did you got that code to compile? The `AjaxBehaviourEvent` class with the UK spelling doesn't exist at all. It's instead in the US spelling `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

Comment: @BalusC Oops, typo. I rewrote the code from scratch when I posted it here. The actual code I've tested is correct (and identical).

Comment: @BalusC I just copied the code in the post and pasted in Netbeans to make sure they're exactly identical now.

Comment: Kudos that you initially wrote it from top of head :) Unfortunately, the problem is not visible in the code posted so far, assuming that this code is executed in a completely blank webapp project with absolute minimum of required configuration and settings (i.e. everything is set to default as much as possible). In your case the best what I can suggest is to run a debugger and track the JSF phases. Or if you have *actually* something more into the code, then head to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: @BalusC I tried to put the code in an empty project, and it works. I'm trying to figure out what difference breakes the code in the real project. You suggest that I track the JSF phases. I know about the PhaseListener interface, and I've successfully registered a PhaseListener, but then what do I do?

Comment: Well, if you already have no idea how to debug, then best what we can suggest is to expand the project with parts of the real project until the problem reoccurs (or the other way round; create a copy of the real project and remove parts until the problem disappears).

Comment: @BalusC I'm already recreating the project. It's going to take a few hours, but so far so good...